# change BIOS interrupt service routine with assembly language

Tags: assembly

I want to replace a BIOS interrupt routine with my own one. But I don't know how to set the value of registers involved. can you tell me the role of cs and ip registers in tracing ISR through a vector table. and if i want to rewrite the routine , what do i need to do?

Comment: If you ask such low level (= close to hardware) question you should specify which architecture/cpu you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole chapter about this in The art of assembly language, [chapter 17](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/art-of-asm/pdf/CH17.PDF). Writing ISRs is quite complicated and involves some problem, such as reentrancy of the code.
Basically you have to change the interrupt vector of the ISR you want to patch to point to your code. This vector is located (if I remember correctly) in a table starting at 0000 segment.
In case mr Hyde refers to other chapters in the book, you'll find a list of PDFs [here](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/art-of-asm/pdf/).

Comment: THX BlackBear. But still There is a problem that the statement mov word ptr es:[0ffh*4], offset SimpleISR
mov word ptr es:[0ffh*4 + 2], seg SimpleISR   wont't compile with NASM,which prompts :"coma, colon or end of line expected"

Comment: @user667139: I think you should use a temp register: mov ax, offset simpleISR; mov word ptr es[0ffh*4], ax; mov ax, seg simpleISR; mov word ptr es[0ffh*4], ax. on which line does it give that error BTW?